# Why is tslint throwing this TypeScript error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am relatively new to Typescript. I am practicing using it with ReactJS and the SpaceX API. I have my interfaces in place and the setup seems to be fine, but I keep getting this error and I can't seem to figure out why. I have given mission_name a type: string in the ILaunches interface, what am I missing here?

In the App component I get the red line under "Launches" in the render/return and the following error:

> ERROR in /Users/******/Documents/ts-spacex/src/App.tsx(11,10):
>   TS2741: Property 'mission_name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.

Here is my App.tsx component:

```
import spaceLogo from './images/spacex.png'
import Launches from './components/Launches'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <img src={spaceLogo} />
        <Launches />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Launches component:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import LaunchItems from './LaunchItems'

interface ILaunches {
  mission_name: string;
}

interface IState {
  pastLaunches: ILaunches[] | null;
}

class Launches extends React.Component<ILaunches, IState> {

  state = {
    pastLaunches: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/past')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ pastLaunches: data })
        console.log('fetch', data)
      })
  }

  render() {

    const launchCards = this.state.pastLaunches.map((launch: ILaunches) => {
      <LaunchItems title={launch.mission_name} />
    })

    return (
      <div>
        {launchCards}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Launches
```

And the LaunchItems component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function LaunchItem(props: any) {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{props.title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Card Subtitle</Card.Subtitle>
        <Card.Text>
          Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
          the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
        <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `mission_name` as props from App Component like `<Launches mission_name='some text'>`

Comment: "mission_name" is one piece of query data from the SpaceX API. It is part of the launch data that I fetched in the Launches component. It is not a prop from the App component in that case then is it?

Comment: Then replace `React.Component<ILaunches, IState>`to `React.Component<{}, IState>`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mahedi Sabuj. Your second solution worked.